# Why doesn't using a shell variable in awk work?

Tags: awk

I'm trying to use awk to solve some problem, but I cannot understand why theese lines don't work.

```
name="root"
ps -eo user:20,rss | awk "{if(\$1==$name) print \$2}"
```

Generally in my system there are a lot of processes, which owner is root, but output is empty.
When I used this:

```
ps -eo user:20,rss | awk '{if($1=="root") print $2}'
```

everything's ok and I've got correct output, but I need to use this variable "name" so I cannot leave it like that. Please help me to spot where is a problem, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run  with `set -x`, and you'll see:

```
$ ps -eo user,rss | awk "{if(\$1==$name) print \$2}"
+ ps -eo user,rss
+ awk '{if($1==root) print $2}'
```

You're missing quotes around `root`, without which awk sees `root` as an awk variable name, not a string.

But if you want to use a shell variable in awk, it's better to do set an awk variable to the shell variable's value:

```
ps -eo user,rss | awk -v name="$name" '$1 == name {print $2}'
```

This also avoids quoting issues, since now awk will expand the awk variable to get the correct text.